# Image mapping and mouseleave event

Tags: jquery, onmouseover, imagemap

I have an **image** using a **map** with some **areas** defined in it.

I need to fire an event when the mouse leaves the image, so I attached one '**mouseleave**' event to the image with jQuery (1.9.1).

Unfortunately when I'm hover one mapped area the event fires.

I need the event firing when the mouse leaves the image only, so if the mouse is hover one area nothing should happen.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: See the jQuery document for http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/. This should do the trick. Without having any code I cant suggest more.

Comment: I saw that but it doesn't help in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with the same issue just today. Problem was that the areas of image map were defined outside of element where the mouseleave event was bound, just like this:

```
<div class="elementWithMouseleaveEvent">
   <img src="something" usemap="map" />
</div>
<map id="#map">
    // areas here
</map>
```

Moving map element inside the div solved the issue:

```
<div class="elementWithMouseleaveEvent">
   <img src="something" usemap="map" />
   <map id="#map">
       // areas here
   </map>
</div>
```